# How to run Xdebug on custom hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

I've set up Xdebug with my PhpStorm and I can debug only from `0.0.0.0`.

**The question is:**
How can I force to run debug process (listening for PHP debug connections) from any other hostname (like: `app.local`)?

**Dockerfile:**

```
....
RUN echo 'xdebug.client_port=9003' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.mode=debug' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.discover_client_host=true' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
...
```

**docker-compose:**

```
...
app:
 environment:
   PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=docker_app
   XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1
 volumes:
   - ./app/.docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

nginx:
 volumes:
   - ./app/.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
...
```

**app.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/app/public;
    client_max_body_size 40M;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

**Servers:**
[image]

Comment: To be frank, 0.0.0.0 is a strange setting. What happens if you remove this record from "Servers", enable "Listen for debug connections" and try to open a webpage, what incoming server connection will appear?

Comment: *"How can I force to run Xdebug (listening for PHP debug connections) from any other hostname (like: app.local)?"* This makes no sense to me.  It's Xdebug that connects to debug client (PhpStorm in your case) and NOT other way around. Therefore Xdebug does NOT listen for anything. It's PhpStorm that does it. I suggest you read how Xdebug works and then check and perhaps reword your question / explain what you are after in the first place.

Comment: @duck_in_hat Thanks for the comment!
Without any server it doesn't work at all.
But I've tried to change `0.0.0.0` to a custom hostname and it worked!
So duplicate your comment as an answer and I'll mark it.